# Should every route return just one database query result?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, express

I was watching a youtube tutorial on postgres and I wanted to get your thoughts on how this database request is handled. In the video we have a backend route to get a restaurant's data by the id. Later on he adds logic to also pull the reviews for the restaurant in that same route.

Would it be a better idea to put the reviews database query in its own get route? You would have to make another axios request to the backend but this way you wouldn't be always pulling the list of reviews down with the restaurant object.

I just wanted to know if I am on the right train of thought here. Thanks in advance!

```
    //Get a Restaurant
    app.get("/api/v1/restaurants/:id", async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id);

    try {
    const restaurant = await db.query(
      "select * from restaurants left join (select restaurant_id, COUNT(*), TRUNC(AVG(rating),1) 
    as average_rating from reviews group by restaurant_id) reviews on restaurants.id = 
    reviews.restaurant_id where id = $1",
      [req.params.id]
    );
    // select * from restaurants wehre id = req.params.id

    const reviews = await db.query(
      "select * from reviews where restaurant_id = $1",
      [req.params.id]
    );
    console.log(reviews);

    res.status(200).json({
      status: "succes",
      data: {
        restaurant: restaurant.rows[0],
        reviews: reviews.rows,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it be a better idea to put the reviews database query in its own get route?   You would have to make another axios request to the backend but this way you wouldn't be always pulling the list of reviews down with the restaurant object.

API design like this depends entirely upon the intended and likely use which you don't really discuss.  A few guidelines to think about.

1. Design the API so you are never making excess database queries (more than the API user actually needs or wants).  This means if the API user sometimes wants only the restaurant's data, but not the reviews, then don't make an API that only gets the the data and the reviews because that would be wasting cycles on the server fetching and transmitting the reviews when the API user doesn't want or need them.
2. A corollary is that it is best for everyone if the API user doesn't have to make multiple requests to get the data they want, but only if you aren't messing with guideline #1.  This is because a single API request will generally perform better, load your server less and be easier for the API user to program than multiple API requests.
3. An API request can specify what information it wants so that you can try to make the design meet the needs of both points #1 and #2 above.  For example, you could add a query parameter to your API request that specifies whether reviews are supposed to be included or not in the results.  Then, the same API can serve the needs of both someone who only wants the restaurant info and someone who wants both the info and the reviews.